# Why are my captions in German?

Tags: languages

I have a problem with the labels of figures and tables in overleaf. For some reason I get them in german and I have no idea why. For figures I get Abbildung or Tabelle for tables.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\input{head}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm, height=5cm]{theta4.png}
\end{figure}

\end document
```

This is the head.tex

```
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2.25cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4.5cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-3.25cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{blindtext} % Package to generate dummy text
\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Use UTF-8 encoding
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel} % Language hyphenation and typographical rules
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb} % Mathematical typesetting
\usepackage{float} % Improved interface for floating objects
\usepackage[final, colorlinks = true, 
            linkcolor = black, 
            citecolor = black]{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{graphicx, multicol} % Enhanced support for graphics
\usepackage{xcolor} % Driver-independent color extensions
\usepackage{marvosym, wasysym} % More symbols
\usepackage{rotating} % Rotation tools
\usepackage{censor} % Facilities for controlling restricted text
\usepackage{listings, style/lstlisting} % Environment for non-formatted code, !uses style file!
\usepackage{pseudocode} % Environment for specifying algorithms in a natural way
\usepackage{style/avm} % Environment for f-structures, !uses style file!
\usepackage{booktabs} % Enhances quality of tables
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} % Easy tree drawing tool
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north},
         level distance=2cm} % Configuration for q-trees
\usepackage{style/btree} % Configuration for b-trees and b+-trees, !uses style file!
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,
            sorting=nyt]{biblatex} % Complete reimplementation of bibliographic facilities
\addbibresource{ecl.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes} % Context sensitive quotation facilities
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime} % Uses YEAR-MONTH-DAY format for dates
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{-} % Sets dateseparator to '-'
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Custom footer text
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Custom footer text
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Custom footer text
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\marginpar{\scriptsize \textcolor{red}{#1}}} % Enables comments in red on margin

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: look into the file "head.tex".

Comment: Ok now I see it. Thank you

Comment: @Mico I added a community wiki answer spelling out the solution explicitly. This should resolve your concern?

Comment: @Davislor - Thanks. I've withdrawn my 'close' vote.

Comment: yiu would find latex a lot less confusing if you cleaned out your preamble, just looking at `graphicx` for example  your main document lists it twice and your `head.tex` lists it a third time.  You should start from an _empty_ preamble  and only add packages that you actually need.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh I know, but at this point I just copy and paste all the packages from my previous work and start from there. I don't want to add packages one by one again :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer noticed, you were including a file named `head.tex`, which included the line,

```
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
```

This sets your default language to German.